# Mongoengine.. reverse the items in ListField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

```
class Example(Document):
    comments =  ListField(field=EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'), db_field='z')

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    comment = StringField()
    date = DateTimeField()
```

how can I reverse the result of comments listfield by Comment EmbeddedDocument'date?
my incorrect code.. is like..

```
Example.objects().order_by('-comments__date')
```

Is there a way to reverse ListField by embeddedDocument's date?
or
just reverse listfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoDB you return items matched by the find statement.  So Doing an:

```
Example.objects().order_by('-comments__date')
```

You are just ordering `Example` objects by the latest comment date.  The query language is for matching so does not change the results / order of the returned list.  You could use a [SortedListField](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.5/apireference.html#mongoengine.SortedListField) that ensures a list is sorted on save if you need to ensure order.  However, there is a possible race condition here as it sets the whole list.  The `$push` operator is best, but it means comments will be a stack and oldest will be appended to the end.

An alternative schema might be desired with `comments` in their own collection or in mongoDB 2.2 the aggregation framework could be used to sort the comments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
Example.objects().order_by('-comments.date')
```